# py2exe is giving errors on my os.listdir code

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe, listdir

When I run my code from main, it runs perfectly fine, but when I try to build main into an exe using py2exe, it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "main.py", line 118, in <module>
    menu.menu.Menu()
  File "menu\menu.pyo", line 20, in __init__
  File "settingsManager.pyo", line 61, in getSetting
  File "settingsManager.pyo", line 148, in __init__
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\digiholic\\git\\universalSmashSystem\\main.exe\\settings\\rules/*.*'
```

The line it's referring to is:

```
for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'settings','rules')):
```

It looks like os.listdir is using unix file pathing to find every file, and Windows is having none of that. Is there a way to use listdir in a way that won't blow up everything?

Comment: Is the path valid? From what I can see, `main.exe` is a file, so further path components don't make sense.

Comment: The forward slash is fine (Windows accepts both). But the files you're looking for won't exist when packaged as an exe.

Comment: So, you're right, main.exe shouldn't be in the path. Why is os.path.dirname(\_\_file\_\_) giving me the file name instead of its directory?

Comment: `diname` gives everything before last slash. `dirname('a/b')` gives `a` but `dirname('a/b/')` gives `a/b`. Print `__file__` to see what you have.

Answer (score 2):

When you're running within the exe you need to check if the module is `frozen`, the path from `__file__` is generally not what you expect when you're within an exe vs the raw python script.  You need to access the location with something like this:

```
import imp, os, sys

def main_is_frozen():
   return (hasattr(sys, "frozen") or # new py2exe
           hasattr(sys, "importers") # old py2exe
           or imp.is_frozen("__main__")) # tools/freeze

def get_main_dir():
   if main_is_frozen():
       return os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
   return os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

Source: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/HowToDetermineIfRunningFromExe
You can also check another direction here: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WhereAmI

Comment: Note PyInstaller has a similar concept described here: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#run-time-information

Comment: How would I go about doing a dirname of files that are deeper in the tree? For example, if I have "<main directory>/stages/arena.py" and arena.py wants to know its own dirname (<main directory>/stages) how would I go about that? Using sys.argv will just give me the main directory.

Comment: I personally use PyInstaller, so I'm not sure exactly how it works with P2Exe when it comes to accessing the embedded files, files relative to the exe/py, etc.  You might just need to do some prints of various methods in and out of the exe, that's what I did the first time dealing with frozen modules.